# activeCheckboxList (Yii2) как поменять значения value?

Tags: php, yii2

Делаю вывод таким способом

```
echo Html::activeCheckboxList($model,'brand',$brands)
```

И получается во такое

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="Search[brand][]" value="1"> Asus</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="Search[brand][]" value="2"> Acer</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="Search[brand][]" value="3"> Lenovo</label>
```

Как сделать так , чтобы в значениях value находился не порядковый номер , а название бренда ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
$brands = ['Asus', 'Acer', 'Lenovo'];
$itemBrands = [];
array_walk($brands, function ($item) use(&$itemBrands) {
    $newBrands[$item] = $item;
});

echo Html::activeCheckboxList($model, 'brand', $itemBrands);
```

Или если у вас есть например модель `Brand` в которой поле `name` хранит имя брэнда(Asus, Acer и т.д.), можно сделать так:

```
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

$brands = ArrayHelper::map(Brand::find()->all(), 'name', 'name');
echo Html::activeCheckboxList($model, 'brand', $brands);
```